# Calling ZipArchive::close() - is it necessary?

Tags: php, zip

I am extending the ZipArchive class and I am opening a zip file in the constructor, then I added `$this->close()` in the destructor. Apparently I need to close the archive earlier in some cases and attempting to close it again in the destructor throws an exception.

The documentation is not very clear on how to check if there is currently a file opened within the object so I was wondering - do I really need to close it at all, since I know that php will automatically close all file handles and stuff at the end of execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZipArchive::close() don't just close the file descriptor but also writes all the central directory data and further metadata, so calling it is mandatory.

Comment: You should call it on archive itself (zip), not the entry.